# How to get the class string from html tag in vscode extension API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to get the class or className string if the opening tag of "h4" is selected in the editor.

```
<div className="App">
  <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
  <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
  <h4 className='color-red rkg
  bg-blue
  test'>Test</h4>
</div>
enter code here
```

Is there any simple way to get the className string, other than iterating on the lines of `editor.document` and figuring out the closing tag of h4 then combining those lines and passing to babel to get the class?

Comment: Have you tried [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)?